# how to inject CacheClient with class library in servicestack

Tags: servicestack

I has a class named `xxxxxx.Bussiness`,it not inheritance `ServiceStack.ServiceInterface`.

but i want to use cache,how do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to access the cache outside of a Service (i.e. a class that inherits from `ServiceStack.ServiceInterface`) then you can use the IoC resolve method to get the instance of the cache.

### Configure Cache Provider:

First you need to register your cache provider with the IoC in the `Configure` method of your `AppHost`. ServiceStack supports a number of providers. (In-memory, Redis, OrmLite, Memcached, Azure). [See here](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Caching) for details on how to configure the required provider. *The example below uses in-memory caching.*

```cs
public override void Configure(Funq.Container container)
{
    // Choose the Cache Provider you want to use

    // i.e. Register in Memory Cache Client
    container.Register<ICacheClient>(new MemoryCacheClient());
}
```

### Resolve the ICacheClient:

Then when you want to use the cache outside of the Service, then you should try resolve the `ICacheClient` using the `HostContext`:

```cs
var cache = HostContext.TryResolve<ICacheClient>();
if(cache != null)
{
    // Use the cache object
    cache.Add<string>("Key","Value");
    var value = cache.Get<string>("Key");
}
```

### ICacheClient provided methods:

This will provide you with access to the cache. `ICacheClient` defines these methods ([Original commented interface definition here](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/master/src/ServiceStack.Interfaces/Caching/ICacheClient.cs)):

```cs
public interface ICacheClient : IDisposable
{
    bool Remove(string key);
    void RemoveAll(IEnumerable<string> keys);
    T Get<T>(string key);
    long Increment(string key, uint amount);
    long Decrement(string key, uint amount);
    bool Add<T>(string key, T value);
    bool Set<T>(string key, T value);
    bool Replace<T>(string key, T value);
    bool Add<T>(string key, T value, DateTime expiresAt);
    bool Set<T>(string key, T value, DateTime expiresAt);
    bool Replace<T>(string key, T value, DateTime expiresAt);
    bool Add<T>(string key, T value, TimeSpan expiresIn);
    bool Set<T>(string key, T value, TimeSpan expiresIn);
    bool Replace<T>(string key, T value, TimeSpan expiresIn);
    void FlushAll();
    IDictionary<string, T> GetAll<T>(IEnumerable<string> keys);
    void SetAll<T>(IDictionary<string, T> values);
}
```

### Cast as your Cache Provider Client:

You can also cast the client to the specific type of your provider, for it's full functionality. For example if we were using the Redis Cache:

```cs
var cache = HostContext.TryResolve<ICacheClient>() as RedisClient; // Typed
if(cache != null)
{
    var mySet = cache.GetAllItemsFromSet("MySetKey"); // Redis specific cache method
}
```

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You have to:

1. register the CacheClient in AppHost

   ```
   public override void Configure(Funq.Container container)
   {
       //...

       container.Register<ICacheClient>(new MemoryCacheClient());

       //...
   }
   ```
2. In your service method use Request.ToOptimizedResultUsingCache

   ```
   public object Get(Task request)
   {
       return Request.ToOptimizedResultUsingCache(Cache,
           UrnId.Create<Task>("Id", request.Id),
           () => new TaskResponse
           {
               Task = TaskLogicService.GetTask(request.Id),
               ResponseStatus = new ResponseStatus()
           });
   }
   ```

There is an [article on ServiceStack](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Caching) that explains Cache usage at greater level of details.

NB: The above snippet asumes use of SS v4.0

Comment: -1 The question was how to use the cache in a class that doesn't inherit from `ServiceStack.ServiceInterface`. The code you have copied from the documentation inherits from the `Service` class, this is where the `Request` object access comes from.